# ReactJs: Is it possible to retrieve the edited value inside this tag <td contentEditable='true'> {this.state.value} </td> tag

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, bootstrap-4

I have searched in many different stackOverflow questions and native html documentation and apparantly there's no way to retrieve the value inside a  :

```
<td contentEditable='true'> {this.state.value}  </td>
```

Apparently there's no native way to retrieve the edited value by the user?
In my app:
[image]

After the user clicks on the green button, I set the **contentEditable** attribute to **true** and hence he is able to edit the right column. However, I've found myself stuck when I wanted to retrieve the new value that the user has typed to send it to the backend!
But this doesn't make any sense, because what's the use of the attribute **contentEditable** if I cannot retrieve the edited value?
I have only found the **onClick listener** which I can use to learn when the user has clicked on a particular cell.
**PS:** I remember in Angular I used to do this easily with two-way data binding..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<td onClick={() => this.setState({ isEditing: true })}>
  {this.state.isEditing ? <input {...yourPropsToHandleInput} /> : {this.state.value}
</td>
```

Comment: That's an interesting way to go around this. But I wish I could do it directly with td. Thank you!

Comment: Although that renders an input inside the table which is not visually friendly really

Answer (score 0):

Instead of {this.state.value} your code should use a component that supports entering information through it. For example, textarea and use its related event functions to send the info to the server.

Comment: I know that. But, my table is already implemented with normal table tags tr,td ...etc. I would like to keep it that simple. However, if I don't find a solution I'll use your tip

Comment: Again,  what's the use of the attribute contentEditable if I cannot retrieve the edited value?

Comment: never used content editable... I preferred the use of components to allow or not the edition of content. React behaves a little bit different than normal html.